# Can't add new component on Mail campaign template in 10.2

Tags: exm, upgrade, campaigncreator

When trying to add `new component` on `mail campaign template` below console error is appearing and component not getting added

Note: This error only appear after I upgrade Sitecore version to `10.2`, issue was not there in `10.1`

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you may still be using files form 10.1. Try copying <root>/sitecore from a vanilla 10.2 site over the top of your solution